# Opening a file in emacs: Values that are not safe

Tags: emacs

When I open the file `zenburn-theme.el` from `github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs.git` in Emacs 24.3, I get the following warning in a buffer:

[image]

Why? Also, why would it not be safe to **open** (not load or run) a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file, even if opened and not loaded, might contain some configuration values to be applied. Some of them are considered unsafe and Emacs asks you about them unless told otherwise. See [Local Variables in Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Why would a file (i.e. the author of the file) require or ask Emacs to apply configuration values when just opening/visiting the file?

Comment: @user815423426: You can set the major mode or encoding of the file with the local variables.

Comment: In the example you gave, the config do activate some mode (rainbo-mode) if available, and do nothing otherwise.